# What are all available struct tag values for encode/json package?

Tags: json, go

Even searched whole document of [encode/json](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json)` ,I still can not find all avaliable tag values."Name" and "omitempty" is all i can get from examples.

Tried:searched on google,github and package.go.
Expecting: get all available tag value.

Comment: Why do you think there's more than in the docs?

Comment: What other than the documentation of the `encoding/json` package would be the source of truth for this information?

Comment: Doc of [`json.Marshal()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) and [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) details all there's to know.